# Adding CMS to a web layout

Tags: php, html, css, content-management-system

I want to add a cms to my web layout for the news and events but what cms is the best for this situation? im new to web development can someone give me some clues or idea. I don't know where to start.

here is my layout:

[image]

Comment: You can use MODx or Drupal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Wordpress is the best for news and blog and also is the best for jump start development if you want to make something custom. It has a huge info on the web for it. You first can start easily learn how to use it to build your web and make it works. After that you can jump on developing for wordpress what you need. It also is developed in php as i see a tag of php here and i guess you wanna start with php.

Answer (score 1):

For tasks like that i preferred Joomla. My approach was:

Using the standard Joomla Template, create a copy of that to have a backup. Change CSS to fit your needs. Use a Borwsertool like Firebug or Webmastertools to find the name of the id's and classes you want to change. Go to the CSS file of the template, change a few lines and save. Reload page and look if it worked. Rinse and repeat. If you are done just create the Content.

It can be a bit irritating at first, but i guess that is with any CMS you use if you are new to CMS. But once you found out how templates and the Backend of Joomla works, you can create individual Designs very fast without the need to wirte thousands of lines in css.